# SharePoint Online - Remove users from the SharePoint sites, when they leave the organization (When their account becomes inactive/expired)

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service

We use SharePoint Online in my work place and we always deal with this issue of removing users/owners manually from SharePoint sites when they leave our organization. Is there a way to automate this process of removing users from sites, when their account gets inactive/expire.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way would be to use PowerShell, utilizing the [SharePoint Online Management shell](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588) module using code like this:

```
$user = "someone@yourdomain.com"
$sites = Get-SPOSite -limit all
foreach($site in $sites){
    try{
        Remove-SPOUser -Site $site.Url -LoginName $user
    } 
    catch{
        write-host $user " does not exist on "$site.Url
    }
}
```

[Remove-SPOUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161381.aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. A quick question - If i provide URL of a site collection as site Url, will this code remove user from the just the root site or all the sub-sites of that site collection?

Comment: It completely removes them from the site collection